# push changes to bare repo in git

Tags: git, shell

I have two git repos.  One contains a file that I modified but did not commit and the other contains no files (it is a bare repo).  How would I push those changes from the one with the modified to the bare repo? I am fairly new to git and unix so any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
wpz23@tux64-12:~/cs265/lab3-git$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   lab3

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   lab3
```

Comment: Push which changes? The "Changes to be committed" as well as the "not staged for commit?" Or just the former?

Comment: Was the local repo cloned from the bare repo? (Does the local repo know about the bare repo?)

Comment: In case you have a misconception, "bare repo" does not mean *"contains no files"*, but: *"contains the database of git objects, without a working tree, and the meta-files are in the root directory of the repo, rather than a `.git` subdirectory."*  Whether or not the remote repo is bare doesn't matter here. Pushing is usually done to a bare repo. If you push to a *non*-bare repo, that can require special handling, if the push affects the branch which is checked out in that repo.

Comment: The fact that the remote repository is a bare repo is irrelevant.

Comment: No the local repo was not a clone. I deleted lab3 and then went back and modified it using `git checkout` Now I am trying to push those changes to lab3-git-bare

Comment: If `lab3` is not a clone of `lab3-git-bare`, then you have to add `lab3-git-bare` as a remote. To learn how to work with remotes, it's best to read a tutorial; it is somewhat broad for one question. Chances are that `lab3-git-bare` has a `master` branch already which is not related to your local master. So that also requires handling.  The easiest way would probably be to commit the changes to some branch other than `master`. Then do a `git pull` from the remote. Choose a suitable branch (`git branch -r` to list remote branches), switch to that branch, and cherry-pick your change, then push.

Answer (score 0):

**Commit**

First you need to commit your changes in your local repository.

```
$ git add lab3
$ git commit
```

http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository

**Add Remote**

Next you should add your remote repository as a remote to your local repository.

```
$ git remote add remote-name http://remote-url.edu
```

http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes

**Push**

Finally you should push your commit to your remote.

```
$ git push remote-name branch-name
```

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push